# Connect 4 Minimax Algorithm (with Alpha-Beta Pruning) in Java

Tags: java, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm trying to write a connect four game with AI using the minimax algorithm and alpha-beta pruning. I know that the heuristic works OK (at the very least it scores 4 in the row very highly), but for some reason my minimax isn't working.

It seems like the problem is that the current score and the minimax score are always equal, when this obviously should not be the case.

The computer frequently makes stupid decisions like going to a random spot when the human is about to get 4 in a row.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciate.

```
public class AI {


public Move minimax(Board b, int depth, int alpha, int beta, String player, Move move) {

    if(depth == 0 || b.boardScore >= 10000) {
        return move;
    }

    else if(player.equals("computer")) {

        Move maxMove = new Move(100,100);
        maxMove.moveScore = -10000000;

        //Do this for every possible column
        for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {

            //If column is filled, move on.
            while(b.findYSpot(x) == -1) {
                x++;
                if(x > 6) {
                    x = 0;
                }
            }

            Move m = new Move(b.findYSpot(x), x); // Create the move

            b.putPiece(player, m.xMove); // Put the piece down
            m.moveScore = b.boardScore;//Set the score the move

            Move miniMaxMove = minimax(b, depth-1, alpha, beta, "human", m);

            // Maximize the score
            if (m.moveScore >= miniMaxMove.moveScore) {
                if(m.moveScore >= maxMove.moveScore) {
                    maxMove = m;
                }
            }
            else {
                if(miniMaxMove.moveScore >= maxMove.moveScore) {
                    maxMove = miniMaxMove;
                }
            }

            b.removePiece(m); //Remove the piece

            //Adjust for alpha-beta pruning
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, maxMove.moveScore);
            if (alpha >= beta) {
                break;
            }

        }           
        return maxMove;
    }

    else {
        Move minMove = new Move(100, 100);
        minMove.moveScore = 10000000;

        //Do this for every possible column
        for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {

            // If column is filled, move on
            while(b.findYSpot(x) == -1) {
                x++;
                if(x>6) {
                    x = 0;
                }
            }

            Move m = new Move(b.findYSpot(x), x); // Make the move

            b.putPiece(player, m.xMove); // Put the piece down
            m.moveScore = b.boardScore; //Set the score the move

            Move miniMaxMove = minimax(b, depth-1, alpha, beta, "computer", m);

            //Minimize the score
            if (m.moveScore <= miniMaxMove.moveScore) {
                if(m.moveScore <= minMove.moveScore) {
                    minMove = m;
                }
            }

            else {
                if(miniMaxMove.moveScore <= minMove.moveScore) {
                    minMove = miniMaxMove;
                }
            }

            b.removePiece(m);

            //Adjust for alpha-beta pruning
            beta = Math.min(beta, minMove.moveScore);

            if(alpha >= beta) {
                break;
            }

        }
        return minMove;
    }
}
}
```